# With the event happening on Friday .. can this imply future tense?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, participle-clauses, future-time

Is it possible to imply the future tense with this construction?

> With the event happening on Friday...
>   With the event to happen to Friday....

Comment: Yes you can as long as you provide a bit of context later in you clause. E.g. "With the event happening on Friday, it promises to be a spectacular affair..."

Comment: Infinitives and participles (both present and past) are *non-finite* forms, meaning they are not 'limited' to a particular tense; the time reference of the action they name is inferred from the context.

Comment: W e l l ... you'll be busy whether or not the meeting takes place. "With the meeting taking place next week I'm afraid prior engagements will prevent me from attending."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible for *with*:gerund clauses like this to have past, present or future reference. Infinitives, past participles and gerund/participles are non-finite forms, meaning they are not 'limited' to a particular tense; the time reference of the action they name is determined by or inferred from the context.

Be careful how you use them, however. These are ordinary *with* preposition phrases where the object of *with* is a clause rather than a nominal. Their purpose is thus not to provide a time reference—if they do, that is incidental—but to provide a state or context for the head clause.

So the first of the examples in your comments is probably an inappropriate use:

> With the meeting taking place next week, I think I will be busy.

This doesn’t work unless your meaning is ironic—you intend to be busy next week **because** the meeting will take place and you don’t want to attend.

Your second example works somewhat better:

> With a press conference taking place in Iraq next week, Obama will face more media scrutiny than usual.

This is OK if what you mean is that the unusual location will cause media scrutiny to be intensified; but it would be better phrased this way, with the location the more emphatic ‘new information’ position:

> With next week’s press conference taking place in Iraq, Obama will face more media scrutiny than usual.

Likewise, if what you want to highlight is the date (I can’t think why you would, but I lack imagination), that should move into the emphatic position:

> With the Iraq press conference taking place next week, Obama will face more media scrutiny than usual.

Comment: To be clear, "with...to do." could also mean future?

Comment: @username901345 Give me a fuller example, please; this is too skeletal for me to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I am sorry about the ambiguity. "with the iraq press conference to take place next week, Obama will face more media scrutiny than usual."

Comment: @username901345 That's iffy; it's grammatical, but on first reading the infinitive seems to be a modifier, "the iraq press conference which is to take place next week", which means something different: "Since there's going to be an Iraq pressconference next week, Obama &c." I would avoid that.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit ambiguous.  Look at these:

> I am happy with the event that is happening on Friday.
>   I am happy with the event that is to happen on Friday.
>   I am happy with the event that will happen on Friday.

If you are asking about the different ways that "happen" is used in these sentences, then the answer is yes.  Here are some simpler examples:

> I am going to the concert on Friday.
>   I am to go to the concert on Friday.
>   I will go to the concert on Friday.

The first one is very common, the usual way to tell someone that you are planning to go to the concert on Friday.  The second one has more of the feeling that it is intended that I will go to the concert.  For example: "I just found out that I'm to go to the concert" usually means that I've been told or ordered to go to the concert.  (BrE will say this in the sense that I wanted very much to go and that the tickets have come through, for example; AmE would say "I've just found out that I get to go to the concert" in this situation.) In any case, you can always substitute the first sentence for the second.

The last one is more often used as an offer, a statement of intent, or a contradiction.  Have a look at these:

> Who wants to go to the concert on Friday?  I will! [or "I'll go!"]
>   If you will pick up the kids on Friday, I will go to the concert.
>   You won't be going to the concert on Friday.  I will too!

The second sentence would generally use contractions: "If you'll pick up the kids, I'll go to the concert."

Comment: Yes, you didn't make that clear, hence my statement that your question is a bit ambiguous.  But I got the idea and went ahead and answered your question.  At least I think I did ("if you're asking about the different ways that 'happen' is used in these sentences, then the answer is yes").  What am I missing?